# How to access a path with spaces

Tags: javascript, html

I create a HTML application on windows 7 and I have a problem with a path with space on a network drive.

The path is : \\network\Projects\1- directory\

They have a space between **1-** and **directory**

Since HTML file I call javascript function to open Excel file like this :

`<button type="button" title="MyExcelSheet" onclick=OpenExcelFile('\\network\Projects\1-&nbsp;directory\MySheet.xlsx')>`

My javascript OpenExcelFile function is :

```
function OpenExcelFile(path){
    var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    Excel.Visible = true;
    Excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
}
```

When I click on the button I have this error message :

```
\\network\Projects\1-&nbsp;directory\MySheet.xlsx not found. Check the spelling of the workbook name and the validity of the location
```

I tested many path with slash, backslash, double slash and double backslah but I have the same problem.

Comment: What makes you think you need `&nbsp;` in the HTML markup? Is it an attempt at a workaround because you forgot to put the `"` around the `onclick` value?

Comment: Hi, If I do not use &nbsp; in the path I have an error message : constant chain not completed, I don't know if the translation is correct because the error message is in french.